# Route how to Change URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I would change my URL in CodeIgniter

I have the following URL:

http://example.altervista.org/girls/show/Megan

I would have:

http://example.altervista.org/show/Megan
I don't want the name of the controller displayed

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
$route['show/(:any)'] = 'girls/show/$1';
```